# jquery to get last highlighted element value

Tags: jquery, listitem

I have a number of `list items` called `selectedli` having with the css `background-color: #efefef;`

I want to get the value of the last highlighted `list item` that has the `selectedli` class applied to it.

This is my code...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $('#btnSelect').click(function() {
        alert( $('#wrapper').find('li').filter("[class=leaf]").last().text() ); //bingo
        alert( $('#wrapper').find('li').hasClass('selectedli').last().text() ); //fail to get value when the class got 2 value inside...
        alert( $('#wrapper').find('li').filter('selectedli').last().text() ); //fail to get value when the class got 2 value inside...
        alert($('#wrapper').find('li .selectedli').last().text());
    });
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="panel" class="cats1">
        <ul id="list_items">
            <li class="root" data-category_id="1">Fashion</li>
            <li class="root selectedli" data-category_id="2">Computer</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="panel" class="cats1">
        <ul id="list_items">
            <li class="root" data-category_id="5">Laptop</li>
            <li class="root selectedli" data-category_id="6">Monitor</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="panel" class="cats1">
        <ul id="list_items">
            <li class="leaf" data-category_id="13">LCD Dell</li>
            <li class="leaf selectedli" data-category_id="14">LCD Acer</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnSelect" value="Select">
```

I can't seem to get my code to work. Could someone please assist me to fix the problem.

Comment: If you solved your problem you should mark one of the answers as correct :)

Comment: thanks guy, I also found my own problem, .find('li .selectedli') will not work, but .find('li.selectedli') will work. Sensitive syntax declaration here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#list_items .selectedli").last().data("category_id");
```

**DEMO** (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/ugdYm/1/

Comment: Oops, made a mistake there - fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do `$("#list_items li.selectedli").last().attr("data-category_id");`

**update**: was missing `last()`

Comment: That will get the *first* item, not the last one

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion, don't use jQuery 1.5 This version has issues.